# Screen Overlay Detected while getting Location permission and than crash

Tags: android, google-maps, location, android-permissions, runtime-permissions

Previously the below code works fine even on The Marshmellow but yesterday i got this eror first time **Screen Overlay Detected** while i am getting the Run time Location permission and during onPause() it `W/Activity: Can reqeust only one set of permissions at a time` and after that crash please help me i even follow so many answers but none is solved my problem.

Code:
OnCreate :

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (!isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Install Google Play Service",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }
    Boolean bool = checkPermission();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        Log.e("overlayPro", String.valueOf(Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)));
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_find_service_providers);
    linearLayout =(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if(null!=intent.getExtras()) {
        //get Intent value
               }
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();

      }
```

onStart() :

```
   @Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    mGoogleApiClient.connect();

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (checkPermission()) {
            mapFrag.getMapAsync(this);
            if (!Utility.isLocationEnabled(getApplicationContext())) {
                setingsrequest();
            }

        } else {
               checkLocationPermission();
        }
    }
    else if (!Utility.isLocationEnabled(getApplicationContext())){
        mapFrag.getMapAsync(this);
        setingsrequest();
    }
    else {
        mapFrag.getMapAsync(this);
    }
     }
```

checkPermission() :

```
 private boolean checkPermission() {
    return (  ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
}
```

settingRequest():

```
 public void setingsrequest()
{

    LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    locationRequest.setInterval(30 * 1000);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5 * 1000);
    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
            .addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
    builder.setAlwaysShow(true); //this is the key ingredient

    PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
            LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(mGoogleApiClient, builder.build());
    result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
            final Status status = result.getStatus();
            final LocationSettingsStates state = result.getLocationSettingsStates();
            switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                    // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize location
                    // requests here.
                    linearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                    // Location settings are not satisfied. But could be fixed by showing the user
                    // a dialog.
                    try {
                        // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                        // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                        status.startResolutionForResult(FindServiceProviders.this, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                        // Ignore the error.
                    }
                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                    // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way to fix the
                    // settings so we won't show the dialog.
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == PERM_REQUEST_CODE_DRAW_OVERLAYS) {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {   //Android M Or Over
            if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {

                Log.e("overlayResult","false");
                // ADD UI FOR USER TO KNOW THAT UI for SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission was not granted earlier...
            }
        }
    }
    switch (requestCode) {
    // Check for the integer request code originally supplied to startResolutionForResult().
        case REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS:
            switch (resultCode) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:

                    linearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    mapFrag.getMapAsync(this);
                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    //setingsrequest();//keep asking if imp or do whatever
                    finish();
                    break;
            }
            break;
    }

}
```

checkLocationPermission()

```
 private void checkLocationPermission() {

            if (!checkPermission()) {

                // Should we show an explanation?
                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

                    // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                    // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                    // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.MyDialogTheme)
                            .setTitle("Location Permission Needed")
                            .setMessage("This app needs the Location permission, please accept to use location functionality")
                            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                    //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
                                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(FindServiceProviders.this,
                                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                                            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
                                }
                            })
                            .create()
                            .show();


                } else {
                    Log.e("overlay","detected but Request New Permission");
                    // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
                }
            }

}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       @NonNull String permissions[],@NonNull int[] grantResults) {

    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                // location-related task you need to do.
                if (checkPermission()) {
                    //allowed
                    Log.e("allowed", String.valueOf(permissions));
                    if (!Utility.isLocationEnabled(getApplicationContext())) {
                        setingsrequest();
                    }
                    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                        buildGoogleApiClient();
                    }

                    mapFrag.getMapAsync(this);

                }else{
                    //set to never ask again
                    Log.e("set to never ask again", String.valueOf(permissions));
                    //do something here.
                }

            } else {

                // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                // functionality that depends on this permission.
                checkLocationPermission();

            }
            return;
        }

        // other 'case' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request
    }
}
```

---

### Updated Code :

```
   @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int permsRequestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {

    switch (permsRequestCode) {

        case R_PERM: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                PermHandling();
            }

            else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 && !shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(permissions[0])) {

                //Previously Permission Request was cancelled with 'Dont Ask Again',
                // Redirect to Settings after showing Information about why you need the permission
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(TestActivity.this,R.style.MyDialogTheme);
                builder.setTitle("Need Storage Permission");
                builder.setMessage("This app needs storage permission.");
                builder.setPositiveButton("Grant", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                        sentToSettings = true;
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                        Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
                        intent.setData(uri);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_PERMISSION_SETTING);
                      //  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Go to Permissions to Grant Storage", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
                builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                builder.show();
            }
            else {

                new AlertDialog.Builder(this,R.style.MyDialogTheme)
                        .setTitle("Location Permission Needed")
                        .setMessage("This app needs the Location permission, please accept to use location functionality")
                        .setPositiveButton("Grant", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(TestActivity.this,
                                        new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                                        R_PERM );
                            }
                        })
                        .create()
                        .show();

            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

In onActivityResult :

```
if (requestCode == REQUEST_PERMISSION_SETTING) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(TestActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            proceedAfterPermission();
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: What does the crash log say ?

Comment: when onPause is invoked it prints thousands time `W/Activity: Can reqeust only one set of permissions at a time
E/overlay: detected but Request New Permission` and than crash

Comment: Something is fishy about your `checkLocationPermission` method try commenting else part and then check

Comment: i tried but after that i never ask for the permission(even for the first time)

Comment: Also, you have again checked for permissions when user denies them in `onRequestPermissionsResult`; this should be handled by just disabling the features that depend on the respective permission as you have written in the comments !!

Comment: oky now i bypass the overaly problem but when tthe user click on the `Never ask Again` checkbox than i prompt the dialog box and than re-direct into the Setting, where user manually provide the location but when the user click on the location toggle button than again Screen Overlay problem is arise plaese check updated code...

Comment: which device are you using?
I have seen this on some devices and it appeared to be a bug as reported [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62125193)

Comment: I am using the Lenovo Tab 3 and the Android Version is 6.0.1

Comment: [check this out](http://www.gadgetraid.com/2016/10/screen-overlay-detected/) and see if this can help you solve your problem !!

Comment: problem solved i just reset my device and now the same code working fine..
I think the problem is caused by the ES File Explorer Application

Comment: Yeah anyways do post an answer here so that it helps others with the same thing.

Comment: sure i will......

Comment: @shadygoneinsane i have a question where i put my this `if (!Utility.isLocationEnabled(getApplicationContext())) {
                setingsrequest();
            }`...
becoz if i put it in onStart() than after onRestart it again called so it creates the two pop-up on the screen